# Add values from a list to each unique ID code [SQL]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of product names (Book, Car, Table). My table currently looks like this:

[image]

What i would like my table to show is all 3 products for each JobID e.g.:

[image]

So essentially for each distinct JobID, there should be 3 products.

How can I do this in SQL? This is a sample dataset, i'm actually working with a much larger and complex dataset but I would like to understand how to do this with a simple dataset and adapt it to my larger dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `cross join`:

```
select j.jobid, p.productname
from (select distinct jobid from t) j cross join
     (select distinct productname from t) p
order by j.jobid, p.productname;
```

Answer (score 0):

*Edited the order by from ordinal positions to actual column names after @Eric's comment.

```
WITH products(  jobId ,productname )
 AS
 (
  SELECT 1200, 'Book' UNION
  SELECT 1400, 'Car' UNION
  SELECT 1600, 'Table' 
 ) 

Select j.jobid, p.productname
from products j
cross join products p
order by j.jobid, p.productname

jobid   productname
1200    Book
1200    Car
1200    Table
1400    Book
1400    Car
1400    Table
1600    Book
1600    Car
1600    Table
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

Comment: Yes. okay to use just for a select but can have serious implications. More so when someone in SO tries to replicate your answer in their live environment.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use cross join,

```
select * from table t1
cross join table t2;
```

Comment: Skip the `ON` clause.

Comment: Select * will produce 4 columns in the output which is different than the expected result.